# Error intergration amazon webservice sdk with spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot

When we intergration amazon webservice sdk with spring-boot application:

```
2013-10-20 16:19:39.279  INFO 393 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 763 ms
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.connectionFactoryLocator': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory] while setting bean property 'connectionFactories' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:665)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:514)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:697)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1068)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:971)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:281)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.<init>(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java:70)
    at org.springframework.social.support.ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector$HttpComponentsClientRequestFactoryCreator$1.<init>(ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector.java:74)
    at org.springframework.social.support.ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector$HttpComponentsClientRequestFactoryCreator.createRequestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector.java:74)
    at org.springframework.social.support.ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector.getRequestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector.java:50)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth1.OAuth1Template.createRestTemplate(OAuth1Template.java:167)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth1.OAuth1Template.<init>(OAuth1Template.java:91)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth1.OAuth1Template.<init>(OAuth1Template.java:75)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterServiceProvider.<init>(TwitterServiceProvider.java:31)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory.<init>(TwitterConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like maybe the Spring Social Twitter uses a different (incompatible) version of the Apache HTTP client libraries than the one needed by Spring 4. If that is the case I'm sure it must be an issue for Spring Social, and it may already be fixed in the latest version. Hard to say for sure unless you can post the entire project (e.g. a project on github would be ideal).